# Find the series expansion of 2 multiplied functions

Tags: sequences-and-series

> The first three terms in the series expansion of $(1+x)^m$ are $1 + mx + \dfrac{m(m-1)x^2}{2}$.
>
> Find the first 3 terms in the series expansion of $(1+x)^{m+1}(1-2x)^m$.

I don't really know how to do this, because I have always done these binomial expansion using binomial coefficients and Pascal's triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to change your variables around so you don't get confused between $x$'s, $m$'s, and other variables. I recommend rewriting your original expansion as follows:

$${(1+x)}^m \implies {(1+u)}^t = 1 + tu + \frac{t(t-1)u^2}{2}$$

Then think of the second expression as using the arguments with particular values of $t$ and $u$:

$${(1+x)}^{m+1}{(1-2x)}^m \implies {(1+(x))}^{m+1}{(1+(-2x))}^{m} \\ = {(1+u_1)}^{t_1}{(1+u_2)}^{t_2}$$ where $u_1 = x; \quad t_1 = m+1; \quad u_2 = -2x; \quad t_2 = m$.

Then you can expand the expression above, using the first expansion, for the subscripted $u$'s and $t$'s to get:

$${(1+u_1)}^{t_1} = 1 + t_1u_1 + \frac{t_1[t_1-1]{u_1}^2}{2} \\ = 1 + (m+1)(x) + \frac{(m+1)[(m+1)-1](x)^2}{2} \\ = 1 + mx + x + \frac{(m+1)(m)x^2}{2}$$

And similarly for the second expression:

$${(1+u_2)}^{t_2} = 1 + t_2u_2 + \frac{t_2[t_2-1]{u_2}^2}{2} \\ = 1+ (m)(-2x) + \frac{(m)[(m)-1]{(-2x)}^2}{2} \\ = 1-2mx+\frac{m(m-1)4x^2}{2} \\ = 1-2mx+2m(m-1)x^2$$

Now all that needs to be done is multiply the two halves of the original product ${(1+u_1)}^{t_1}{(1+u_2)}^{t_2}$:

$${(1+u_1)}^{t_1}{(1+u_2)}^{t_2} = \left( 1 + mx + x + \frac{(m+1)(m)x^2}{2} \right) \left( 1-2mx+2m(m-1)x^2 \right)$$

At this point, the product is just tedium to find the first 3 terms of the expansion you're looking for.

Comment: That's clever, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Taylor series technique if you are familiar with it. Here are the three desired terms

$$ 1+ \left( 1-m \right) x + \frac{m}{2}( m-7) \,{x}^{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert #1 \right\vert}%
 \newcommand{\yy}{\Longleftrightarrow}$

$\large\tt Hint:$
\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\pars{1 + x}^{m + 1}\pars{1 - 2x}^{m}}
=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{m + 1}{m + 1 \choose \ell}x^{\ell}
\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{m}{m \choose \ell'}\pars{-1}^{\ell'}2^{\ell'}x^{\ell'}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{m + 1}{m + 1 \choose \ell}x^{\ell}
\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{m}{m \choose \ell'}\pars{-1}^{\ell'}2^{\ell'}
\sum_{n = 0}^{2m + 1}x^{n - \ell}\delta_{n - \ell,\ell'}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{2m + 1}x^{n}
\sum_{\ell = 0}^{m + 1}{m + 1 \choose \ell}\pars{-1}^{n - \ell}2^{n - \ell}
{m \choose n - \ell}\sum_{\ell' = 0}^{m}
\delta_{\ell',n - \ell}
\\[3mm]&=
\sum_{n = 0}^{2m + 1}x^{n}\bracks{%
\sum_{{\vphantom{\Large A}\ell\ =\ 0} \atop {\vphantom{\LARGE A}0\ \leq\ n - \ell\ \leq\ m}}^{m + 1}{m + 1 \choose \ell}{m \choose n - \ell}\pars{-1}^{n - \ell}
2^{n - \ell}}
=
\color{#0000ff}{\large\sum_{n = 0}^{2m + 1}a_{n}x^{n}}
\end{align}

> $$
> a_{n}
> \equiv
> \sum_{{\vphantom{\Large A}\ell\ =\ 0}
>       \atop
>       {\vphantom{\LARGE A}n - m\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ n}}^{m + 1}
> {m + 1 \choose \ell}{m \choose n - \ell}\pars{-2}^{n - \ell}
> $$

\begin{align}
a_{0}
&=
\sum_{{\vphantom{\Large A}\ell\ =\ 0}
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\LARGE A}-m\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ 0}}^{m + 1}
{m + 1 \choose \ell}{m \choose 0 -\ell}\pars{-2}^{-\ell} = 1
\\[3mm]
a_{1}
&=
\sum_{{\vphantom{\Large A}\ell\ =\ 0}
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\LARGE A}1 - m\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ 1}}^{m + 1}
{m + 1 \choose \ell}{m \choose 1 - \ell}\pars{-2}^{1 - \ell}
\\[3mm]
a_{2}
&=
\sum_{{\vphantom{\Large A}\ell\ =\ 0}
      \atop
      {\vphantom{\LARGE A}2 - m\ \leq\ \ell\ \leq\ 2}}^{m + 1}
{m + 1 \choose \ell}{m \choose 2 - \ell}\pars{-2}^{2 - \ell}
\end{align}